# How to access to the top of the stack in xv6?

Tags: stack, xv6

I'm trying to access to the top of the stack for the main process in xv6. How i must do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Comment: Which stack? Every process has two stacks; the user stack and the kernel stack.